# Is it possible to see a difference between mouse click and obj.click()?

Tags: javascript, button, click

Lets say there is a form with a submit button. I found out that using javascript i can call the `click()` method for input elements in Firefox which would simulate the mouse click on that element.

But then, i got this question, can you detect if button was clicked with real computer mouse, or `.click()` method?

Thank you

Comment: `.click()` ? or you mean `.onclick()` ?

Comment: .click() is what i mean. onclick doesn't work this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger a test using `onmousedown` from the element in question.

Keep in mind the following though:

- If your `type="submit"`, you can use the same function that envokes `.click()` to just submit the form like ~`formName.submit();`
- If `type="button"` and for some reason you have an onclick event handler that submits the form, your onclick events will be invoked whether you call `.click()` or actually click the button.
- onmousedown events will not be called using `.click()`.